# Building JARs with different JDK versions through Maven

Tags: maven, java

We are currently busy upgrading to Java 1.7.  Unfortunately, as these things go, a number of applications cannot be compiled under 1.7 and breaks (even with the override flag passed to 1.7). The plan is to re-factor these asap.

I would like to configure Maven in such a way that different JDKs can be used based on some property in the POM. I followed http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/compile-using-different-jdk.html to the letter, but no matter what I do, maven ignores the java specified in the POM.

The POM has the following entry:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <compiler-version>1.6</compiler-version>
                <executable>/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin/javac</executable> 
                <debug>true</debug>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
...
```

Furthermore, I get no output from the 'verbose' flag -- which I find odd.  Maybe the above is completely ignored?

EDIT: I know it is not working, since inspecting the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file shows the incorrect java version. The version used corresponds with the javac in the current path.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven
Built-By: jaco
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_147-icedtea
Implementation-Title: xxx
Implementation-Vendor: xxx
Implementation-Version: 1.3.7
Specification-Title: xxx
Specification-Vendor: xxx
Specification-Version: 1.3.7
```

EDIT: Something else that is rather interesting.  If I purposefully break the file reference in , I get:

```
[INFO] Compilation failure
Failure executing javac,  but could not parse the error:
/bin/sh: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk: Permission denied
```

EDIT: I suspect the problem lies with the component building the manifest file.  If I break java 7 on my machine (i.e. rename javac to javac.pleasegoaway), it compiles!! However, the manifest files still reports version 1.7.  This is now past annoying and getting hilarious.

Some help will be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Did you make the changes to settings.xml like the documentation suggests in your link?

Comment: I did, but as it didn't work, I hard-coded the paths to bypass it altogether.

Comment: Is the <plugin> tag correctly within the <project><build><plugins>  tags?

Comment: Good point... but sadly, yes (I've updated the above).

Comment: How is the compiler plugin being executed, from the normal mvn lifecycle, or directly?  Have you tried running "mvn compile"  directly to to see what errors you get?  Try running it with the -e flag if an error is thrown.

Comment: You may also want to try "mvn clean install" if you haven't yet.

Comment: I'm using "mvn clean package" on the command line.  I have tried all variants as well.  The wrong version gets used... could it possibly be that the manifest file is incorrectly populated?

Comment: Check out one of the class files using this command to see if it is indeed being compiled in 1.7, and the manifest is just wrong:  "javap -verbose MyClass"

Comment: Tried that too... It reports major version 50 (i.e. 1.6), but that could only mean that the Java 1.7 compiler compiled the class for 1.6.  Is there a way to determine the actual compiler version used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

compiling and jar-ing are 2 separate operations.  the fact that complation errors when you change the compiler path indicates that compilation is happening correctly.  most likely the maven jar plugin is using the java7 jar tools to create the jar file.

Comment: Hi jtahlborn - I suspect you may be right.  It seems like the jar-operation is using the incorrect version to jar the classes.  I will confirm this by using a diamond operator in the code and then compiling.  I should then break... (I did not downvote you, if this works I'll gladly give you a +1 and an answer tick then :))